# UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 64, 1]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I am trying to run a neural network model with batch size of 64, DNA sequence length of 1000. DNA sequences are one hot encoded like image having (1000,4) tensor structure.

This is my simple model :

```
class model_test(nn.Module): # deepcre model  
def __init__(self,
             seq_len: int =1000,
             kernel_size: int = 8,
             p = 0.25): # drop out value 
    super().__init__()
    self.seq_len = seq_len
    # adjusting window size corresponding to sequence length 
    window_size = int(seq_len*(8/3000)) # 8/3 =^ 2.6 
    
    # CNN module
    self.conv11 = Conv1d(4,64,kernel_size=(kernel_size),stride = 1,padding = 1)
    self.relu11 = ReLU()
    self.maxpool1 = MaxPool1d(kernel_size=window_size)
    self.Dropout1 = Dropout(p)
    self.fc1 =Linear(497,1) #batch_size_init*(seq_len//window_size) , 1) # 1000-2*1-1/2 

def forward(self, x):
    """Forward pass."""
    
    x = x.permute(0,2,1)
    x = self.conv11(x)
    x = self.relu11(x)
    x = self.maxpool1(x)
    x = self.Dropout1(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)

    return x
```

Training :

```
def loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb, opt=None,verbose=False):
    '''
    Apply loss function to a batch of inputs. If no optimizer
    is provided, skip the back prop step.
    '''
    if verbose:
        print('loss batch ****')
        print("xb shape:",xb.shape)
        print("yb shape:",yb.shape)
        print("yb shape:",yb.squeeze(1).shape)
        #print("yb",yb)

    # get the batch output from the model given your input batch 
    # ** This is the model's prediction for the y labels! **
    xb_out = model(xb.float())
    
    if verbose:
        print("model out pre loss", xb_out.shape)
        #print('xb_out', xb_out)
        print("xb_out:",xb_out.shape)
        print("yb:",yb.shape)
        print("yb.long:",yb.long().shape)
    
    loss = loss_func(xb_out, yb.float()) # for MSE/regression
    # __FOOTNOTE 2__
    
    if opt is not None: # if opt
      
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        opt.zero_grad()

    return loss.item(), len(xb)


def train_step(model, train_dl, loss_func, device, opt):
    '''
    Execute 1 set of batched training within an epoch
    '''
    # Set model to Training mode
    model.train()
    tl = [] # train losses
    ns = [] # batch sizes, n
    
    # loop through train DataLoader
    for xb, yb in train_dl:
        # put on GPU
        xb, yb = xb.to(device),yb.to(device)
        
        # provide opt so backprop happens
        t, n = loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb, opt=opt)
        
        # collect train loss and batch sizes
        tl.append(t)
        ns.append(n)
    
    # average the losses over all batches    
    train_loss = np.sum(np.multiply(tl, ns)) / np.sum(ns)
    
    return train_loss

def val_step(model, val_dl, loss_func, device):
    '''
    Execute 1 set of batched validation within an epoch
    '''
    # Set model to Evaluation mode
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        vl = [] # val losses
        ns = [] # batch sizes, n
        
        #torch.set_grad_enabled(True) ##### need confirmation where to use or even to use them 
        # loop through validation DataLoader
        for xb, yb in val_dl:
            # put on GPU
            xb, yb = xb.to(device),yb.to(device)

            # Do NOT provide opt here, so backprop does not happen
            v, n = loss_batch(model, loss_func, xb, yb)

            # collect val loss and batch sizes
            vl.append(v)
            ns.append(n)

    # average the losses over all batches
    val_loss = np.sum(np.multiply(vl, ns)) / np.sum(ns)
    
    return val_loss


def fit(epochs, model, loss_func, opt, train_dl, val_dl,device,patience=1000):
    '''
    Fit the model params to the training data, eval on unseen data.
    Loop for a number of epochs and keep train of train and val losses 
    along the way
    '''
    # keep track of losses
    train_losses = []    
    val_losses = []
    
    # loop through epochs
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # take a training step
        train_loss = train_step(model,train_dl,loss_func,device,opt)
        train_losses.append(train_loss)

        # take a validation step
        val_loss = val_step(model,val_dl,loss_func,device)
        val_losses.append(val_loss)
        
        print(f"E{epoch} | train loss: {train_loss:.3f} | val loss: {val_loss:.3f}")

    return train_losses, val_losses


def run_model(train_dl,val_dl,model,device,
              lr=1e-2, epochs=epoch_init, 
              lossf=None,opt=None
             ):
    '''
    Given train and val DataLoaders and a NN model, fit the mode to the training
    data. By default, use MSE loss and an SGD optimizer
    '''
    # define optimizer
    if opt:
        optimizer = opt
    else: # if no opt provided, just use SGD
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    # define loss function
    if lossf:
        loss_func = lossf
    else: # if no loss function provided, just use MSE
        loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    
    # run the training loop
    train_losses, val_losses = fit(
                                epochs, 
                                model, 
                                loss_func, 
                                optimizer, 
                                train_dl, 
                                val_dl, 
                                device)

    return train_losses, val_losses
```

I have to get output torch.Size([64,1]) because i set batch_size as 64. But instead of i get torch.Size([64,64,1]). Can Someone help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output shape by using the following code:

```
batch_size = 64
sequence = 1000
dim_model = 4
input = torch.rand(batch_size, sequence, dim_model)
model = model_test()
output = model(input)
print(output.shape)
```

Result:

```
torch.Size([64, 64, 1])
```

If you want the output shape to be [64,1]. You need to flatten before adding the Linear layer. I have modified your code a bit:

```
class model_test(nn.Module):  # deepcre model
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_len: int = 1000,
                 kernel_size: int = 8,
                 p=0.25):  # drop out value
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        # adjusting window size corresponding to sequence length
        window_size = int(seq_len*(8/3000))  # 8/3 =^ 2.6

        # CNN module
        self.conv11 = Conv1d(4, 64, kernel_size=(
            kernel_size), stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu11 = ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = MaxPool1d(kernel_size=window_size)
        self.Dropout1 = Dropout(p)
        # batch_size_init*(seq_len//window_size) , 1) # 1000-2*1-1/2
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*497, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        """Forward pass."""

        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
        x = self.conv11(x)
        x = self.relu11(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.Dropout1(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
```

Result:

```
torch.Size([64, 1])
```